# WidgetKit on Mac with Intent doesn't work

Tags: macos, widgetkit, macos-big-sur

I am trying to make a WidgetKit widget for macOS Big Sur. The widget itself works -- the same code on both the Mac and iOS. The issue is that *on the Mac* the intent (settings) does not work. When I click "Edit Widget" the options I defined do not appear. When I press "Done," it's replaced with a screen that says "Unable to load."

This seems to happen with a brand new target and just a simple new text parameter. These are the steps I took:

1. Create a new Mac project
2. Add a new Widget target
3. Change the generated Intent, adding a parameter. You also need to add a "Siri Dialog Prompt"
4. Click "Run"
5. Click "Info" in the Widget Simulator
6. Click "Configure Intent"

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

This has been an issue since at least Big Sur beta 5 and Xcode 12b6. I opened a ticket with Apple, but I'm also asking here as it seems that some people have it working and it's entirely possible that I'm missing something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an older copy of the app on my disk and macOS getting confused and looking in the wrong place.

I'm adding a Widget to an existing app that doesn't currently have one. I have the current, App Store version in /Applications. I've been running the updated version from Xcode or exporting it to my desktop and running it from there. The Widget itself -- as noted in the question -- runs just fine. But it seems that when looking for the Intent used for the configuration, it prefers to look in /Application rather than the Xcode version. As soon as I deleted the original app, the widget and its settings immediately started working.

Thanks to [Ely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5131026/ely) for pointing me to [this blog](https://www.rambo.codes/posts/2020-09-08-creating-configurable-widgets-for-macos-big-sur) which didn't give the answer but pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug of the Widget Simulator. When I run the same Widget in the Widget panel of Big Sur, I see all configuration options.

Comment: Are you doing something different to me? I get the same behaviour in the simulator and the notification center.

Comment: Make sure that you add the Sandbox entitlement to the Widget project. This article https://www.rambo.codes/posts/2020-09-08-creating-configurable-widgets-for-macos-big-sur (and the referred Git project) that I found today may contain some additional useful info and clues.

Comment: @Ely Your comment savesd me. I have to add Sandbox entitlement not only to Widget extension but to IntentHandler as well.